# Count integer with Thread in Activity and update Canvas in View

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-canvas

I'm developing my first android game without xml files for layouts in eclipse. This is calling MyGameView.class(extends View) from MyGameActivity.class(extends View implements OnTouchListener)

```
 MyGameView myView;
 myView = new MyGameView(this);
 myView.setOnTouchListener(this);
 setContentView(myView);
```

Everytime, I touch (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN), I update the Canvas in MyGameView.class with the following code. This is the code I use to update MyGameView.class from MyGameActivity.class.

```
 myView.invalidate();
```

Yes it works!But I got a serious problem now.I need to move Canvas in MyGameView.class by every 0.3 second.I use Thread to update but it forced stop!!!! I tried again and again and again! I failed!

```
 public void runtime() {
 i = 0;
 Thread timer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (i<1500) {
            try {
                 Thread.sleep(300);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                 if (right) {
                     i++;
                     //This is static int a from MyGameView.            
                     MyGameView.a += 2;
                     myView.invalidate();
                 }
                 else {
                     i = 1500;
                 }
             }
       }
  }
});
timer.start();
```

}

Updating Static int or boolean to MyGameView.class from MyGameActivity.class with myView.invaldate(); is working. But I can't control it with Thread! Is there something wrong with my Thread running code?

It's probably up to Thread because I can move +2 along X-axis to right everytime I press (MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN).

```
 //I can Move with this code but not with Thread!
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      MyGameView.a += 2;
      myView.invalidate();
 break;
```

With Thread, it stops! Please give me a solution for this! In other words, I need to count with time without error and update canvas on every count!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalidate must be called from the UI thread. Try calling

```
postInvalidate()
```

instead.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate()) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, you are the key!!! It works. I could die!!! ha ha ha Thank you like a million times!!

Comment: @Steven you should accept the answer as the right one, since it helped you

Comment: Please forgive me because I just signed up to this and asked so I didn't know about that.